# qgis installation error on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ppa, qgis

I am trying to install QGIS in ubuntu 20.04 following this (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) instruction .When I tried to install the QGIS signing key with command :

```
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2020.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg
```

it gives output :`gpg: key F7E06F06199EF2F2: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key gpg: key F7E06F06199EF2F2: "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2020) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>" not changed gpg: Total number processed: 1 gpg:              unchanged: 1` 
and i tried the next command to add the qgis repo ,it gives this error:

```
Repository: 'deb https://qgis.org/debian groovy main'
Description:
Archive for codename: groovy components: main
More info: https://qgis.org/debian
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel. 
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-groovy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-groovy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-groovy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-groovy.list
Ign:1 https://qgis.org/debian groovy InRelease                                 
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Err:3 https://qgis.org/debian groovy Release                                   
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 104.21.71.41 443]
Hit:4 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                     
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [110 kB]     
Get:7 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease [115 kB]    
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:9 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease [101 kB]  
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,676 B]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,856 B]
Get:12 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages [345 kB]
Get:13 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [37.7 kB]
Get:14 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [6,108 B]
Get:15 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [133 kB]
Get:16 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [25.6 kB]
Get:17 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:18 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [600 B]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
W: https://qgis.org/debian/dists/groovy/InRelease: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://qgis.org/debian/dists/groovy/Release: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
E: The repository 'https://qgis.org/debian groovy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What should i do?

Comment: Other then being totally unreadable are you sure you are trying to download is in the place you think it is? Near the end of this question it says E: The repository 'https://qgis.org/debian groovy Release' no longer has a Release file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)